# Preventing search engines from indexing Wordpress uploads

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

A client has requested that all files within the /uploads directory within Wordpress to not be listed by search engines. I have tried the following within `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/
```

And also adding the following to `.htaccess` and changing my browsers user agent to Googlebot, however I can still view the files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot
RewriteRule ^.*$ /404 [L,R=301]
```

Is there an error in any of the above, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When did you make these changes? It will take some time for the changes to get reflected in the google results. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq?csw=1#h18

Comment: @Hariprasad I made these changes about 3 weeks ago - would have thought that would be enough time considering the profile of the site in question.

Comment: @wickwills As per the FAQ, you can submit a request via the google webmasters tool. May be you can try that.

Comment: @Hariprasad I have asked the client to add our email to their webmaster tools account - no response yet. Just a bit curious as to why the above didn't work - especially the htaccess method. Though I'm far from an expert in editing .htaccess! :)

Comment: Do you have the `RewriteEngine on` line? One more thing to note is that the RewriteRule should not be 404. It will negatively affect your SEO ranking. Better redirect to your home page URL

Comment: @Hariprasad Yep, I do have that line - I'm unable to show the full htaccess file here though - the above is just the relevant snippet that I've attempted to get working.